# Redirect page via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

hello I have an indexed page, whose url: `website.ext/recensione/43-Dungeons--Dragons-Neverwinter-PS4`

Unfortunately I had to change the structure in the url: `website.ext/recensione/43-dungeons--dragons-neverwinter-neverwinter---un-dd-allennesima-potenza`

There is no way to make the redirect via .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to your htaccess file and it will work.

```
RewriteRule ^recensione/43-Dungeons--Dragons-Neverwinter-PS4$ /recensione/recensione/43-dungeons--dragons-neverwinter-neverwinter---un-dd-allennesima-potenza? [L,R=301]
```